# How to hide/not to display ionic loader for specific http api calls in ionic project

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

am working on ionic project. i got the issue with ionic loader. am calling multiple http apis from different methods. here's the issue is for every specific api call the loader getting triggered so please can any helpme out to hide or not to display loader for specific api calls in ionic.

Comment: For Ionic 1 or Ionic 2?

Comment: Using only ionic 1 not ionic 2.

Answer (score 0):

For **Ionic 1** you can use [$ionicLoading](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/)

```
angular.module('LoadingApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('LoadingCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
  $scope.show = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Loading...',
      duration: 3000
    }).then(function(){
       console.log("The loading indicator is now displayed");
    });
  };
  $scope.hide = function(){
    $ionicLoading.hide().then(function(){
       console.log("The loading indicator is now hidden");
    });
  };
});
```

Additional example:

```
.controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$ionicLoading',
    function($scope, $timeout, $ionicLoading) {
        $scope.functionName= function() {
                $ionicLoading.show({
                    template: 'Loading...'
                var url = 'http://myapi.php';
                $timeout(function() {
                    Data.getdata(function(data) {
                        $scope.getdata = data;
                    }, url);
                    //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
                    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
        $scope.functionName();
    }
])
```